# Adding additional description to variable in Gurobi with C#

Tags: c#, gurobi, ampl

I want to add additional despription of variable instead of making it as a constraint. I already did it in AMPL like this:

```
var z {p in route} = sum{n in nodes}s[p,n];
```

So far, I already make the code in Gurobi with C# like this, but it doesn't work. It said: "`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Gurobi.GRBLinExpr' to 'Gurobi.GRBVar'`"

```
GRBVar[] z = new GRBVar[P];     //variable of route
GRBVar[] y = new GRBVar[M];     //variable of depot
GRBVar[,] s = new GRBVar[P,N];     //auxilary variable

for (int p = 0; p < P; p++)
 for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
 s[p, n] = master.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "s" + p + "," + n);

for (int p = 0; p < P; p++)
{
GRBLinExpr sumS = 0.0;
for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
{
sumS += s[p, n];
}
z[p] = sumS;
};

 for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
 y[m]=master.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "y" + m);
```

Comment: Gurobi does not have `defined variables`. You need to make it an explicit constraint.